# C#: No overload for 'listView_ItemDrag' matches delegate 'System_Eventhandler'

Tags: c#

I have a form on which I create a ListView in my code (ControlArray) and I need to add another eventhandler to it. I get the error from the title on this line:

```
    //Listview events
        listViewData.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listView_SelectedIndexChanged);
        listViewData.ItemDrag += new EventHandler(listView_ItemDrag); <-- Error here
```

And this is the event (I created it by adding a listview to the form, add the event and then delete that listview):

```
    private void listView_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            //Declaratie
            ListViewItem dataItem = (ListViewItem)sender;

            //Lijst aanmaken en opvullen
            DataObject verplaatsing = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, dataItem);

            //beginnen met slepen
            dataItem.ListView.DoDragDrop(verplaatsing, DragDropEffects.Copy);

        }
    }
```

Help is much appreciated because I have a deadline coming up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
listViewData.ItemDrag += new ItemDragEventHandler(listView_ItemDrag);
```

Comment: That's it, thanks so much. I couldn't find an answer anywhere :-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is in you using `+= EventHandler`

ItemDrag has `ItemDragEventHandler`